# Can we create URL fragment links to answers on the same page?

Tags: feature-request, answers, hyperlinks

I tried putting a link to an answer in the comments of another answer *on the same page* using the share link.

That works, but the link that takes you to show the answer involves a page reload.

Is there a way we can put URL fragment links to answers, such as using `[#answer2](link to answer)`?

Basically, a way which will navigate to the answer which is on the same page without causing the page to reload.

To ease the way of adding links to posts instead copy/paste it should be something like what github does, example if I am writing `[internal link](#)` as soon as I type `#` to give the url, it pops out the available answer urls on that page and links them.

*Update:* We can use `#id`, where `id` is the id of the answer, to target them directly but I think it still reloads the page.

[Example link to answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358847/3950422)

Comment: Good request, but it'll take 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @davidism - I disagree with the duplicate suggestion, as the proposed approach there causes a page reload.

Comment: [go to answer without reload](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358846/can-we-create-url-fragment-links-to-answers-on-the-same-page#answer-358847)

Comment: Just a test @Oleg, if you came to this comment through notification. try clicking your above link, see if it does reload the page.

Comment: @bhansa Yep, it broke my solution ;(. Changing the title will also probably break it.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a good idea, and it would be ridiculously easy to implement as well.

If you were so inclined, you can create these yourself. Creating URL fragments require a legitimate target to use, and in the case of linking to same page answers luckily the `id` of the element will work.

The id of the answer element is the same as the value in the share link prefaced by `answer-`. So, for example if the share link was `https://stackoverflow.com/a/47037297/1026459`, then the id you are looking for is `47037297`. Now, using your example above, creating a link is easy. `<a href="#answer-47037297">local link</a>` would work.

It is unfortunately impossible to create such a link at present which is where this feature comes into play. Using `[local link](#answer-47037297)` simply creates the text version of that. If the regex tester for the `[]()` format would *also* permit the `()` section to start with a `#` then users could manually form these links themselves with little issue and create the URL fragment links.

So, the easy part here I think would be to allow a link to be converted into an anchor element when in the format of `[]()` if the parameter for `()` starts with `#`.

Comment: good example, and thanks for editing the question.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully the question edit reflected your original intent, that was at least what I had interpreted. I think it is a good idea.

Comment: It's possible [test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358846/can-we-create-url-fragment-links-to-answers-on-the-same-page#answer-358847) `[test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358846/can-we-create-url-fragment-links-to-answers-on-the-same-page#answer-358847)` [go to question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358846/can-we-create-url-fragment-links-to-answers-on-the-same-page#question)

Comment: I see, the title seems to be a requirement in the link as far as creating a shortcut. That said, as I navigated to this question again from the url related to your comment link, the test did cause a page reload at first.

Comment: Yes, it's far from perfect.